# How can I programatically determine how many VBA pages in a MultiPage

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a program to convert all Userforms in a VBA application to Web pages using HTML, CSS3, and JavaScript.  I have it mostly done, but there are a few controls that are more complex to convert.  My question is:  How can I programmatically determine how many VBA pages in a MultiPage?

Comment: I tried in the immediate window: "? userform22.MultiPage1.Pages" but that does not work.

Comment: Try `UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages.Count`, changing the name of the controls accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Domenic. that works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @Domenic in comments:

```
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
```

Comment: @Dominic I have replicated your comment as answer here. If you wish to get rep for it please leave a message here and I will delete this.